# adding a reset button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am very green and starting to learn JS, just started my small project for practice.
I found my "reset" button is no longer working, would you guys pls hv some comments? Thanks a lot.

```
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="clear()">
function clear(){
document.getElementById("result").value.reset();}
```

Comment: What is your "result" element?

Comment: `FormElement.reset()` resets a form, if that's what you want... or maybe you want something like `document.getElementById('result').value = 'some value here';`

Comment: Yea, Although my question is stupid but you guys are helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch out, clear is already taken, you should rename your function:

```js
function clearResult(){
  document.getElementById("result").value = ''
}
```

```html
<input id="result" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="clearResult()">
```

See for example https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/clear

Answer (score 0):

Change

`document.getElementById("result").value.reset()`

to

`document.getElementById("reset").reset();`

And also, rename `clear` to some other function as [`clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/clear) is a reserved word and does something entirely different.

```js
 function myFunc() {
     document.getElementById("reset").reset();
 }
```

```html
  <form id="reset">
    Name<br><input type="text"  name=""><br>
    foo<br><input type="text" name=""><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunc()" value="Reset">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this error that I figured out. First thing if you want to use reset() then, use the following code:

```
<form id="result">
<input type="text">
  <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="clear1()"></form>
<script>
function clear1(){
  document.getElementById("result").reset();}</script>
```

So if you see here, I have used the  tag. Three errors I found in your markup were:

1. clear() method is already reserved in javascript. clear() method in JavaScript is used for the removal of all the elements from a map and make it empty. So, instead use any other function name like clear1() just like I did.
2. reset() function works for the  tag. So instead of giving input tag an id give that id to the  tag.
3. You don't have to use the value in reset() method
   Use this method when you have a lot of input tags to perform with. Just wrap it with a  tag.

Another method is easy when you have only one or two  tags.

```
<input type="text" id="result">
  <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="clear1()">

<script>
function clear1(){
document.getElementById("result").value= ''}
</script>
```